Explain why "Calf" is the answer to "Ice mass broken off a little lower?"
This question is 18 across in puzzle No 33, The Sun Two-Speed Crossword book...

Q: Ice mass broken off a little lower?


A: Calf

Some of my thought processes are: Ice (diamonds?); ice mass (iceberg?); mass (religion, weight, throng?); broken off (removing letters?); little lower (maybe indicating to a small "moo-er", i.e. calf? But I don't know why).

This clue is

 a double definition. You already hit on the second one - a calf, i.e. a small cow, is a little thing that lows (low being another word for the sound a cow makes - see sense 2 here). The first is a less-common definition of calf - when an iceberg or glacier breaks apart, it is called calving, and a mass of ice that has broken off in this manner is also called a calf (see sense 1, definition 5 here).


Indeed, the verb form of calving is fairly common in this context, but I've only rarely seen the noun form referring to the resulting ice floe as a calf.

You should make it explicit in this answer that the verb "low" is a synonym of "moo", since they say "I don't know why"
